# Embed external site into page and interact with content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, iframe, cross-domain

I'm trying to load an external website on a page and interact with the content, for example add event listeners (for the content of the external site loaded). This won't work on an iframe as I can't interact with the content, I tried to do it using react, and when I want to add event listeners to the iframe I get the following js error `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

I thought it was just not possible but then I saw this video from a tool that seems to do that: https://youtu.be/qinZviJajcw?t=21

Does anyone have an idea on have this could be accomplished?

thanks!

Comment: The demo shows http://import.io - I believe they proxy the remote website through their servers to bypass CORS and other cross-site scripting prevention measures, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: so you mean they might be rendering the site from the server?

Answer (score -1):

By the looks of it, you do not have Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) setup. For ASP.NET, check the following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1#setting-up-cors

Specifically, you will need to modify the Startup.cs file to enable CORS.

If you are not using ASP.NET, then I recommend that you Google CORS for whatever web back-end you are using.

Comment: The OP wants to load a third-party website into their own using iframes and client-side scripting. The OP's own server-side code is irrelevant because the browser is not making CORS requests to the OP's site, but to the third-party site.

Comment: i don't think this is what i was asking for